# <View/> in XML,parse error

Tags: android, xml

I use  in my XML file,but sometimes error occurred.
the code:

```
 <View
android:layout_height="7dip"
android:layout_width="7dip"
android:background="@drawable/grey_solid_icon"/>
```

it is a dot view,and it occurred by chance.
    the error:

```
android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #75: Error inflating class 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at mypageName.getView(MyClass.java:165)
```

Comment: Didnt understand your question! What do you mean by sometime error occured?

Comment: @UzairQaiser sorry,I mean this error happened randomly

Comment: kindly Update Your question with Activity code too.